# Как привязать Select2 от kartik к данным vue (через v-model)

Tags: vue.js, yii2

Я использую ActiveForm в Yii2. В форме используется виджет Select2. Как привязать его v-model vue. Если вставить в options - не видит изменения.

Answer (score 0):

в интернете масса постов по интеграции select2 и vue, есть даже готовые компоненты, например, https://github.com/godbasin/vue-select2
вообще vue и yii2 виджеты это взаимозаменяемые вещи - серверная часть на yii должна возвращать json c данными для построения форм и прочих элементов, а vue компоненты обеспечивать их отрисовку